# what is the issue in this javascript short circuit assignment

Tags: javascript

The following javascript code is getting giving undefined as the final output. But as far as I know the OR ' || ' operator will stop the evaluation as soon as it gets "true". But in this block of code it is trying to evaluate the remaining conditions even though it gets true on the first expression.

```
field = {
    ipaddr: "0.0.0.0",
    nodePresentInTopo: false
}

var bestName = field.ipaddr || (field.ip6addr && field.ip6addr != '::') ? field.ip6addr : undefined || field.sysid;
```

Here bestName always evalueavtes to undefined but why? As it is getting the value at field.ipaddr i.e 0.0.0.0

Please explain the logic.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think ? : swallows the whole expression from unless you put it into parentheses ()

Comment: The result can be `field.ip6addr`,`undefined` or `field.sysid`, **all of which are `undefined`.**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `fields != field` - typo?

Comment: @deceze yes it is evaluating the second condition ((field.ip6addr && field.ip6addr != '::')) but it should not go for it right? as it is getting the value on first expression.

Comment: Your condition is `a || b ? .. : ..`. Once again: `(a || b) ? .. : ..`! If you have some specific logical *grouping* in mind you should set parentheses yourself, instead of relying on operator precedence (which is not what you expect in this case).

Comment: You should be easily able to debug this yourself by printing every variable in that expression into console.log() or by using a debugger.

Comment: Please make it more verbose, but readable. If it takes 10 minutes to understand a one liner maybe it's better to write 10 readable lines of code?

Comment: Hi guys please check the given fiddle link.https://jsfiddle.net/8nb5awg5/

Answer (score 2):

In one word: [**operator precedence.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Yes, `||` short-circuits and doesn't evaluate the second half *of the expression used as condition in the ternary operator*.

```
field.ipaddr || (field.ip6addr && field.ip6addr != '::') ? .. : ..
```

Evaluates to:

```
'0.0.0.0' ? .. : ..
```

Which evaluates to `true` and then evaluates the `true` branch of the ternary operator:

```
field.ip6addr
```

If you want a different logical grouping, use parentheses:

```
field.ipaddr || (.. ? .. : ..);
```

Comment: still can you explain why it tried to evaluate the true branch of ternary operator

Comment: Because that's how the logical grouping shakes out due to the [**operator precedence.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) Your entire `ipaddr || (ip6addr .. )` expression is taken as the *condition* to the ternary operator.  Because `||` has a higher precedence than `?:`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know that you've written `field.ipaddr` instead of `fields.ipaddr`. Probably for testing purposes. If the last part of the expression is your problem, write it like so:

`(undefined || fields.sysid);`

Comment: corrected the typo mistake. its still giving same answer "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so is there any property with name `ip6addr` in current object?

```
var bestName = (field.ipaddr || (field.ip6addr && field.ip6addr != '::') ? field.ipaddr : undefined || field.sysid);
undefined
```

Either you should add `ip6addr` in current object or replace with appropriate property

Comment: no there is no ip6addr property in the case but it can be for other cases this is a part of a large plugin i have just copied a portion of it

Comment: Please console.log (field)  and check whether this property is part of your field object just before your turnary operator