# Improve conditional statement syntax

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I would like to refactor this conditional statement to shorten the code if possible. I have tried the ternary operator which didn't work. Any other suggestions?

```
if(err == null) {
    console.log("connected successfully!");
}
else {
    console.log(err);
}
```

I expect the same `console.log` statements to be reached.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [short-circuit `||` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270082/2764486) to log either the error, or if error is `null`, your success message.

```js
console.log(err || "connected successfully!");
```

Comment: btw, that's nicer than the equivalent ternary `err ? err : "connected successfully!"`

Answer (score 0):

a) You should check that `err === null` or better `!err`. note the extra `=`. Why? because `undefined == null` is `true`. I humbly suggest you to read more on strict equality in Javascript.

b) The ternary expression would look like this: `err ? console.log(err) :     console.log("connected successfully!")`

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried ternary operator which didn't work

Tbh, that statement makes little sense, unless your claiming your browser or node has an error in its implementation of the operator.

Ternary operator:

`console.log(err == null ? 'connected successfully!' : err);`

Answer (score 0):

But a ternary would work? See below... note that the text is logged to the console because the first side is triggered when the test is *true*

```js
const err = null
err == null ?  console.log("connected successfully!") : console.log(err)
```